# Access manifest placeholder values programmatically in code Android

Tags: android, android-manifest, placeholder

I am using some manifest place holder values. As per our new requirement, I have to programmatically access those values from my code.  Is there any way to achieve it?

```
manifestPlaceholders = [
    host_name: "dev.com",
]
```

Comment: Define the same values in Gradle using `buildConfigField`, then referencing them via `BuildConfig`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to access manifest place holder values programmatically. I had to put the same values in **buildConfigField**

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else was wondering how this is done:

- define variable in Gradle:

`def variable = "YOUR VALUE HERE"`

- use this variable for manifest placeholder value:

`manifestPlaceholders.variableName = "$variable"`

- use the same variable for build config value:

`it.buildConfigField "String", "VARIABLE_NAME", "\"$variable \""`